# Two composite indexes or one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries that are as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE asset_type=%s AND country=%s AND series=%s
SELECT * FROM table WHERE asset_type=%s AND country=%s AND episode=%s
```

Should I add one composite index, including all four fields? Or two composite indexes, one for each query?

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX (asset_type, country, series)
ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX (asset_type, country, episode)
-- or --
ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX (asset_type, country, series, episode)
```

Why should I choose one over the other?

Comment: What table engine is used and what is the exact table schema? Like, what is PK here?

Comment: None of the above are PK here. It's auto-incremented. `InnoDB`.

Comment: Okay, then Gordon's answer is good :-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax "field=%s". What does it mean?

Comment: @TommCatt just some variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to maximally optimize both queries, then use two indexes.

If the `asset_type` and `country` fields are highly selective -- meaning that they select very few of the rows in the original table -- then the one index will work.  Note that for the second query, the first two keys will be used to find a position in the index to start scanning.

Comment: What do you mean by 'highly selective' for those two items? Do you mean it has a low cardinality, or what exactly?

Comment: @David542 yep, they meant that it must be of a high cardinality.

Comment: @David542 . . . I mean that the results are of low cardinality.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "then the one index will work" --- for only one index to work they must be of a *high* cardinality.